# XML Batch import to MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have spent hours on something that I thought would be fairly simple. A little bit about my environment. I am using PHP 5.4.23 and MYSQL 5.5.32 and its a shared hosting account with GoDaddy. That said this is my problem.

I have a copy of an XML file on my server and I'd like to load it into my db (localhost). I am able to execute all XSL statements and my SQL user had all privileges. The script I try to execute is:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'http://www.hunt-buddy.com/arcole/feeds/bigcommerce/inventory/prods.xml' INTO TABLE temp ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<SKURcrd>';
```

I have the table setup on my table (temp) and there are no records. The error I keep getting is:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I have read a lot of the documentation on the MySQL site but have made no progress. In addition, I have remotely connected (terminal) into the SQL server and run the command (without PHP) and I get the same error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Akshay

Comment: maybe try in phpmyadmin and use the import tab

Comment: Thanks for that. But, I have to create an automated job that runs every day at a certain time!

Comment: maybe skip the `http://` portion and use an absolute path like `/arcole/feeds/bigcommerce/inventory/prods.xml`

Comment: mysql isn't going to fetch a file from a url for you. you've specified `LOCAL`, and are trying to point to some remote resource. it's not mysql's job to implement web client functionality just so it could (maybe) try to fetch a remote file for you. that's NOT its job.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what the issue was. Apparently, I was not on the correct version of PHP? I changed it in cPanel and it has started to work (the correct number of records are being imported but the data is all null). Onward into figuring this out. 

Thanks to all that helped!

Comment: And the null values were because I had a data type mismatch!